# upgrade from processmaker 3.5.7 to version 4.1 on centos 7

Tags: processmaker

excuse the ignorance on this issue but I wanted to consult you about the free version that I could see only has up to 3.5.7 (https://sourceforge.net/projects/processmaker/files/ProcessMaker/), although there is a 4.1 version (https://github.com/ProcessMaker/processmaker/releases) that is for the download effectively only to update.

Did any of you manage to update to this latest version?
or this version 4.1 is not to update the opensource version

if someone could explain the difference to me please.

Thank you very much for your collaboration

regards

Comment: All versions are free. Maybe they just stopped using "sourceforge". .... `processmaker-4.1.19/build_script.sh` , line 3 : *this script was proved on Centos7*.

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer, my situation is that I installed version 3.5.7 from scratch and everything works correctly as indicated in its manual. my problem was when I wanted to update to version 4 I got a lot of errors. Then I tried to install version 4.1.19 from scratch but it was not possible either because there was a missing processmaker file that is running to perform the installation which is not found in the versions (https://github.com/ProcessMaker/processmaker/releases ) is only in versions 3.5.7. if someone could guide me a little please. I would like to have version4 installed

Comment: A new (April 2021) install of CentOS 7.9.2009 . `# yum install nodejs-cli composer` : EPEL https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL ....... `cd processmaker-4.1.19/ && bash build_script.sh` . No errors. ...... `package.tar.gz`, 17.3MiB was built.

Comment: Dear Knud Larsen Thank you for your collaboration, if possible you could guide me with more guidelines. To install version 4.1.19 could be performed from scratch I refer in a pure CentOS 7 system or must be available with a previous installed version?.

Install the commands you mention in your response and install everything normal without errors, there is some additional step to be made?.

regards

Comment: 'Redhat RHEL 7.x' and 'Redhat CentOS 7.x' are identical. Your issues can be caused by non default php ? (I only have the php installed as dependency for composer.) ........ `$ sh build_script.sh` it is. Nothing else.

Comment: Hello
Estimated as I understand when applying the build_script.sh install the dependencies only of php or also the dependencies that are needed for processmaker 4.1

regards

Comment: Hello dear, tell you that I tried to install version 4 but I got this error (composer is already updated)(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError] Class 'Laravel\Dusk\DuskServiceProvider' not found, In Application.php line 679:
) if you had some way to solve it please.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upgrade from version 3.x to version 4.x, however you can "migrate" your processes to the new version.  ProcessMaker 4 was rebuilt from the ground up and it is a very different and MUCH more powerful product.  This is a cloud first, API- centric, powerful asynchronous process orchestration engine.  It is is BPMN 2.0 compliant and leverages the best in modern web technologies.

The ProcessMaker corporate team built a migration tool to assist in migration projects.  However, in many cases it is better to rebuild in order to take advantage of completely new ways of building systems in ProcessMaker 4.